# What is the compatible version of Junit 4, powermock and springboot version 2x

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm currently using versions as :

springboot-version : 2.0.1.RELEASE

Junit-version : 4.12

Powermock-module-junit4-verison : 1.6.4

Powermock-api-mockito-version : 1.6.4
I need a compatible version for all these, as I'm migrating my code from springboot-1x to 2x

Getting this error :

```
   org.testng.TestNGException:
Failure in JUnit mode for class com.snapdeal.payments.disbursement.api.impl.XXX
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:107)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69)
        at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:697)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.runJUnitWorkers(TestRunner.java:1004)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:728)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:629)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerFactory.create(Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;)Lorg/mockito/internal/InternalMockHandler;
        at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:109)
        at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:59)
        at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:203)
        at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:106)
        at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:54)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.ja
va:282)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
        ... 22 more
```

and this also :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;
        at com.snapdeal.payments.disbursement.api.impl.XXX.<init>(XXX.java:41)
```